# How to change the title of the Yii -> ECSVExport

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I have a problem downloading all the data from the database and throw them into cvs in more or less this way:

```
Yii::import('ext.ECSVExport');
            $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Id = $id');
            $export = new ECSVExport($command);
            $data = $export->toCSV();
            Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile('sales_order.csv', $data, "text/csv", false);
```

my database table looks something like this

```
id  O_NUMBER    O_TYPE  O_VAR1  O_VAR2  O_VAR3
```

That's the problem with the export gets the title names of the tables from the database and not, for example:

```
id  NUMBER  TYPE    VAR1    VAR2    VAR3
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify your query and use aliases for the columns.

f.i.

`"SELECT id, O_NUMBER AS 'NUMBER', O_TYPE AS 'TYPE', ... FROM table_name WHERE Id = $id"`